# How to merge two unequal rows of a pandas dataframe, where one column value is to match and another column is to be added?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, merge

I have given the following pandas dataframe:

```
    d = {'ID': ['1169', '1234', '2456', '9567', '1234', '4321', '9567', '0169'], 'YEAR': ['2001', '2013', '2009', '1989', '2012', '2013', '2002', '2012'], 'VALUE': [8, 24, 50, 75, 3, 6, 150, 47]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    print(df)

         ID  YEAR  VALUE
    0  1169  2001      8
    1  1234  2013     24
    2  2456  2009     50
    3  9567  1989     75
    4  1234  2012      3
    5  4321  2013      6
    6  9567  2002    150
    7  1169  2012     47
```

I now want to merge two rows of the DataFrame, where there are two different IDs, where ultimately only one remains. The merge should only take place if the values of the column "YEAR" match. The values of the column "VALUE" should be added.

The output should look like this:

```
         ID  YEAR  VALUE
    0  1169  2001      8
    1  1234  2013     30
    2  2456  2009     50
    3  9567  1989     75
    4  1234  2012      3
    5  9567  2002    150
    6  1169  2012     47
```

Line 1 and line 5 have been merged. Line 5 is removed and line 1 remains with the previous ID, but the VALUEs of line 1 and line 5 have been added.

I would like to specify later which two lines or which two IDs should be merged. One of the two should always remain. The two IDs to be merged come from another function.

I experimented with the groupby() function, but I don't know how to merge two different IDs there. I managed it only with identical values of the "ID" column. This then looked like this:

```
    df.groupby(['ID', 'YEAR'])['VALUE'].sum().reset_index(name ='VALUE')
```

Unfortunately, even after extensive searching, I have not found anything suitable. I would be very happy if someone can help me! I would like to apply the whole thing later to a much larger DataFrame with more rows. Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: So in other words, the second ID (`4321`) should be suppressed in the output, in favor for trumping `1234`. How should the algorithm decide which ID is the resulting one?

Comment: @hc_dev I will pass the two IDs to be merged to this manually from another function! Maybe it is possible to specify that the first ID passed should be left? I am open for ideas!

Comment: @hc_dev The later DataFrame will have many thousands of rows with many different IDs and two different IDs should always be merged, which are located somewhere randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just group on 'ID' and take the max YEAR and sum VALUE:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'YEAR':'max', 'VALUE':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
     ID  YEAR  VALUE
0  1234  2013     27
1  4321  2013      6
```

Or group on year and take first ID:

```
df.groupby('YEAR', as_index=False).agg({'ID':'first', 'VALUE':'sum'})
```

Ouptut:

```
   YEAR    ID  VALUE
0  2012  1234      3
1  2013  1234     30
```

Comment: First, thanks for your quick efforts!!! The second output goes already in the right direction. However, my goal is to merge two rows in a DataFrame with well over 10 000 rows. In doing so, the two rows to be merged will be located somewhere randomly. Do you have a solution for this? Maybe my example was too simple, sorry.

Comment: @Alfonso Use pd.concat the results of this groupby with the original dataframe, so the results are at the bottom.

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't choose which two IDs will be merged and which will be left? You really have to imagine this in a DF with many rows and many different IDs (and YEARs). I would like to specify which two IDs will be merged and which of the two will be left.

Comment: I am sorry @Alfonso, I don't quite understand.  Can you make your test case more complex and show the expected output?

Comment: I have made the example more complex, thanks for the hint. I hope you can understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the comments and update to the question it sounds like the **logic** (maybe not *this exact code*) is required...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID': ['1169', '1234', '2456', '9567', '1234', '4321', '9567', '0169'], 'YEAR': ['2001', '2013', '2009', '1989', '2012', '2013', '2002', '2012'], 'VALUE': [8, 24, 50, 75, 3, 6, 150, 47]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(int)

def correctRows(l, i):
    for x in l:
        if df.loc[x, 'YEAR'] == df.loc[i, 'YEAR']:
            row = x
            break
    return row

def mergeRows(a, b):
    rowa = list(df[df['ID'] == a].index)
    rowb = list(df[df['ID'] == b].index)
    if len(rowa) > 1:
        if type(rowb)==list:
            rowa = correctRows(rowa, rowb[0])
        else:
            rowa = correctRows(rowa, rowb)
    else:
        rowa = rowa[0]
    
    if len(rowb) > 1:
        if type(rowa)==list:
            rowb = correctRows(rowb, rowa[0])
        else:
            rowb = correctRows(rowb, rowa)
    else:
        rowb = rowb[0]
        
    print('Keeping:', df.loc[rowa].to_string().replace('\n', ', ').replace('     ', ' '))
    print('Dropping:', df.loc[rowb].to_string().replace('\n', ', ').replace('     ', ' '))
    
    
    df.loc[rowa, 'VALUE'] = df.loc[rowa, 'VALUE'] + df.loc[rowb, 'VALUE']
    df.drop(df.index[rowb], inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)
    return None

# add two ids.  First 'ID' is kept; the second dropped, but the 'Value'
# of the second is added to the 'Value' of the first.
# Note: the line near the start df['ID'].astype(int), hence integers required

# mergeRows(4321, 1234)

mergeRows(1234, 4321)
```

**Outputs:**

```
 Keeping: ID   1234, YEAR 2013, VALUE  24
Dropping: ID   4321, YEAR 2013, VALUE   6
```

**Frame now looks like:**

```
ID  YEAR    VALUE
0   1169    2001    8
1   1234    2013    30  #<-- sum of 6 + 24
2   2456    2009    50
3   9567    1989    75
4   1234    2012    3
5   9567    2002    150
6   169     2012    47
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my hero. (And also thanks again to everyone else who tried to provide a solution).